# DocDb Emulator missing functions

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I'm using DocumentDb emulator in my dev environment. I simply downloaded it from the provided link and the local version is 1.11.72.11.

In the Explorer view, I don't see any of the functions to manipulate my database or documents e.g. save, create document, etc. that appear in the intro video.

This is what's in the video:
[image]

And this is what I see on my local version:
[image]

Any idea why those functions are missing and how I can fix this?

Comment: Looks like you're comparing a web interface to the emulator app's interface.

Comment: I'm not aware of an app interface for the emulator. Is there one? Clearly, in the video, they're using the DocDb emulator through a browser.

Answer (score 1):

Just got an email response from the DocDb team that they were able to reproduce this issue and they're working to correct it.

Comment: This is better as a comment, as it's not really an answer.